# Tell google an alternative spelling of a word

Tags: xml, search-engine, google-search

I have a website that is written in English, but many of the visitors search for it in danish.

So they would search for "MyWebsite København", where the text google indexes from the site is "MyWebsite Copenhagen".

I've done a bit of testing and it seems google isn't quite smart enough to figure out to search for Copenhagen, when the user is searching for an alternative spelling of a city-name.

I know Google has alot of ways of how you can help it understand your content - But I have been unable to find out how to tell it which city it is.

Maybe there is a way to suggest an alternative spelling to the search-engine som when the site is indexed it would understand that both MyWebsite København and MyWebsite Copenhagen is actually the same.

Looking forward to any suggestions :-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a question for webmasters. Voting to move